# Wordpress : Create independent page for a post

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry if I am not clear but I am looking for a way to display in an independant template the comment of a given post or something else (of the given post). I don't understand at all the process.

- I have a post : `website.com/postname`
- I want to display only comments of the post here : `website.com/postname/comment`

If you could give me a beginning of answer...

Comment: I would look into creating a custom post type with the parent being a post

Comment: Thank you ! Do you have a suggested link where I could find more ?

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/ For an intro to Custom post types, and https://generatewp.com/post-type/ for generating the boilerplate code :)

Comment: The reason I haven't posted an answer is because your solution is kind of vague and it would require me to write ~3-4 files from scratch which I don't quite have the time to do. Sorry.

Comment: Yes sure :) I want to be more specific in order to find the best solution. I have a major problem and I am trying to resolve it with some tips... I have some mapped domain in my single installation (I don't want to use MU). If I access my post with the second domain, I am not going to be logged and that's a basic security thing. But the problem is I can't post comment with my admin account because I am not logged, so the idea was to add an iframe with the original url where I am logged but I don't want to load the whole page...

Comment: I will suggest you to create a page named "Comment" or "Comments" with custom page template named, there you will get the ID of a single post. After that you can get comments of a post using WP REST API. Note but the url will gonna be like website/comment/postname. 2nd way using add rewrite endpoint in single post and make an if else conditional,this url gonna be like example you given above.